# How to add child node for selected tree view node

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

am binding tree view from database ,and i have a button add node in my page.
when i select a node in tree view then i click add node button am showing a popup with name text box.when i click add button i want to add child node for selected node in tree view
i want to insert selected node id as parent and name
Html Helper

```
  <a href="#@i.EmpID">@i.Name</a>
```

am taking id here
adding node

```
 <input type="text" name="MasterName">
           @Html.ActionLink("Add", "addMaster", "Treeview")
```

controller

```
public ActionResult addMaster(string ID)
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: Depends on which tree view library you are using. did you look at that library's documentation to see whether they allow adding an item ? Have you tried  that ?

Comment: yes sir, it will allow